# How can I subtract two alias columns?

Tags: pervasive

I need to find the difference between two columns that have an alias.

The error I get is: "Error in Expression: Highest_Cost - Lowest_Cost" Invalid Column name: Highest_Cost

Here is my query:

```
select part,min(cost) as Lowest_Cost,max(cost) as Highest_Cost, min(date_received) as First_date, max(date_received) as Last_Date, description, Highest_Cost - Lowest_Cost as Difference
from v_po_history 
where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-04-01' and date_received <= '2022-04-30' 
and location = 'HS'
group by part,description
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling for an hour I couldn't find an answer. I post this question and my next google search, I find the answer. basically you have to run the calculation again. you can't access alias' columns in the select statement they are declared.

```
select part,min(cost) as Lowest_Cost,max(cost) as Highest_Cost, min(date_received) as First_date, max(date_received) as Last_Date, description, (max(cost) - min(cost)) as Difference
from v_po_history 
where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-04-01' and date_received <= '2022-04-30' and location = 'HS'
group by part,description
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    x.Highest_Cost - Lowest_Cost AS Difference
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        part,
        MIN(cost) AS Lowest_Cost,
        MAX(cost) AS Highest_Cost,
        MIN(date_received) AS First_date,
        MAX(date_received) AS Last_Date,
        description
    FROM v_po_history
    WHERE
        part NOT LIKE '*%'
        AND date_received >= '2022-04-01'
        AND date_received <= '2022-04-30'
        AND location = 'HS'
    GROUP BY
        part,
        description
) AS x;
```

With SQL queries, the way that you write queries [isn't the way that queries are processed](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you).

In your example specifically, columns in the select list are projected last, and so the aliases aren't bound to the expressions when you're trying to reference the aliases *again* in the select list.

By sticking the initial query in a derived table, you can select from the derived table and reference the aliases since you're selecting from that initial result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erik. Do you think this solution is better/more efficient than the fix I found in my reply?

Comment: @SkylarP That's something only you can answer. Run both and look at the query plans and execution times.